# Missing Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client and other DLLs in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I have a new installation of Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 on Windows 7. It seems that I'm missing all of the libraries related to TFS. I have nothing under this folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation." I have tried repairing the install and that didn't help. What else should install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2015 and later Microsoft changed the location at which these assemblies reside. They reside in a strangely named folder under the

*"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions"*    directory

for me it was under the *"4t4m3e1u.n25"* folder, do check under the Extensions folder and you should get all the required dlls there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the if the Team Explorer is installed and working for you (*If you open Visual Studio and the Team Explorer pane doesn't appear, click the **View/Team Explorer** menu option*.).

Whatever, For the 2015 release, we have removed the client OM DLLs from the GAC.

These have been moved into a Nuget package, see [NET client libraries for Visual Studio Online (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries) for details.

You can download the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package from nuget.org and import into your Visual Studio projects.